# How can duplicated pairs be removed from two arrays in Java?

Tags: java, arrays

```
a = [1,3,5,7,9,3]
b = [2,1,7,9,5,1]
```

`a[5]` & `b[5]` is a duplicated of `a[1]` & `b[1]`. Is there any way to remove all the duplicated pairs from the two arrays? Any help would be great.

Comment: can you show us your attempts?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), have a look around, and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). From that second link: "Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it."

Comment: I have no idea how to do that... :(

Comment: The straightforward solution: For each item in the first array, iterate on all items in the second array. If it's found there, remove it (print it or whatever you want to do).

Comment: Create a `Set` from each array, you'll have only unique elements.

Comment: do you want to remove duplicate pairs or keep one of them ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy way to do this :

- create a `Set` (no duplicate) of Pairs (one value from `a`,one value from `b`)
- add the values of the set to the arrays

---

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] a = new int[]{1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 3};
        int[] b = new int[]{2, 1, 7, 9, 5, 1};

        Set<Pair<Integer, Integer>> set = new LinkedHashSet<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
            set.add(new Pair<>(a[i], b[i]));
        }

        a = new int[set.size()];
        b = new int[set.size()];
        int i = 0;

        for (Pair<Integer, Integer> pair : set) {
            a[i] = pair.getKey();
            b[i] = pair.getValue();
            i++;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be optimizable, but this is working fine.
This only deletes the duplicate, and conserves an original.

```
Integer[] a = {1,3,5,7,9,3};
Integer[] b = {2,1,7,9,5,1};

ArrayList<Integer> al = new ArrayList<Integer>();
al.addAll(Arrays.asList(a));

ArrayList<Integer> bl = new ArrayList<Integer>();
bl.addAll(Arrays.asList(b));

HashMap<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
int i = 0;

while( i < al.size() -1 ){    
    map.put(al.get(i),bl.get(i));    
    i++;                  
}

int y = map.size();
Integer[] af = map.keySet().toArray(new Integer[y]);
Integer[] bf = map.values().toArray(new Integer[y]);

System.out.println((Arrays.asList(af)).toString());
//Output : [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
System.out.println((Arrays.asList(bf)).toString());
//Output : [2, 1, 7, 9, 5]
```

Comment: I think the idea is to remove _pairs_ that are duplicated, considering each "pair" to be one element from `a` and one element from `b`. Your solutions remove duplicate elements from each array separately, which does not seem to be what the OP wants. Plus, solution 1 does not preserve order.